# Python, recursively reduce a list (combinations/permutations)

Tags: python, list, lambda, reduce, fold

I'm trying to make a generic function that would reduce a list like so :

```
func(['a','b','c'],str.join) # --> ['a','b','c','ab','ac','bc','abc']

func(['a','b','c'],lambda: a,b:a+'x'+b) # --> ['a','b','c','axb','axc','bxc','axbxc']
```

I don't really know how to do it. I did a few tries, but none was successful. 
I'm pretty sure there is a way to do it with reduce but i'm not very comfortable with the use of this function. Here are some attempts :

```
reduce(lambda a,b:[a,b,str(a)+str(b)],['a','b','c'])

reduce(str.join,['a','b','c'])
```

I think i'm missing a recursion somewhere.

I'm not asking for code especially, any help or advice is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you're reducing a list here, rather your outputting various permutations.

Comment: You're not very comfortable means it does not work, or it simply does not look nice to you?

Comment: It means, i know how it works, i prefer using such functions when it is possible, but i still have difficulties to use it.

Comment: You're looking for powersets, see the recipe on the itertools page: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools.combinations` will give you all combinations of a certain length. We take all the combinations for each possible sublist length. We then map the function you were interested in (the lambda function, or in this case `"x".join`) to each of the generated combinations.

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> l = [map("x".join, list(it.combinations(a, l))) for l in range(1,len(a)+1)]
>>> l
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['axb', 'axc', 'bxc'], ['axbxc']]
```

Now `l` is a list of lists that we want to flatten:

```
>>> [ x for y in l for x in y]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'axb', 'axc', 'bxc', 'axbxc']
```

Answer (score 3):

How's this?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def func(mylist, letter):
...     L = []
...     for i in range(len(mylist)):
...             L.append(list(itertools.combinations(mylist,i+1)))
...     return [letter.join(i) for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(L)]
... 
>>> func(['a','b','c'], 'x')
['a', 'b', 'c', 'axb', 'axc', 'bxc', 'axbxc']
```

Comment: @ibi0tux You're welcome :). I'm actually editing my answer now to make it a function :3